# MYSQL DISPLAYING ROWS WITH SIMILAR SPECIFIC VALUE IN A SPECIFIED FIELD

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I'm quite new to mysql i have a table containing 2 columns and 3 rows. the columns are known as ROWNUM and LATITUDE.
Can anyone suggest a query i could use to display all the rows that have a specified value in LATITUDE column. for example :

```
ROWNUM | LATITUDE
1      |   35.8
2      |   35.8
3      |  -23.5
```

I would like to display at the end of this the rows containing 35.8 in the 
LATITUDE COLUMN e.g:

```
1 | 35.8
2 | 35.8.
```

Comment: Seriously? This is like 101 select statement. Google, you know the search engine?

Comment: Please stop shouting

Answer (score 2):

Use a WHERE statement to filter records with an specific LATITUDE.

```
SELECT ROWNUM, LATITUDE
FROM   YOUR_TABLE
WHERE  LATITUDE = 35.8
```

Comment: Thanks it worked brilliantly